# Segmentation Fault from basemap.Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, matplotlib-basemap

I have installed basemap using

```
conda install basemap
```

I can import using

```
import mpl_toolkits.basemap as bm
```

but calling

```
bm.Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0.0,lat_0=0.0)
```

or any other projection, I get a "Segmentation Fault"

I am running on Fedora these versions:

Python 3.4.2 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)
IPython 2.2.0
matplotlib                1.4.2 
basemap                   1.0.7 
numpy                     1.9.1

Thanks for any help and suggestions you have.

Comment: Try running with `python -X faulthandler` and see if you get a useful traceback at the segfault.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this error. It was caused by mixed geos version installed in my system. The error is gone after removing all geos installation and re-install the latest version.